# In-line fan installation

Tags: exhaust-fan, fans

Can an In-line bathroom fan be installed horizontally or just vertically ? Been searching all over but no manufacturer specify that on their guide. Thank you

Comment: If the installation manual doesn't say "Don't do it", then it's probably OK.

Answer (score -1):

Typically or by default "in-line" means either orientation is intended. One advantage to vertical is bearing wear. The fan won't be fighting gravity & its own weight. Other than that, call or email a few manufacturers & see what they say or if they have specific or better models for your application.